# $localStoage not Working in Service Response

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, local-storage

i am working in angularjs + SpringMvc. I am using $LocalStorage in Angularjs for storing user data. In angularjs controller $localStorage work fine. but in HTTP POST response it not working. don't it have some scope problem or what else.

here is my angularjs controller Code

```
App.controller('LoginController',function($scope,$http,$window,$localStorage ) {
$scope.submit=function()
{
    var formData={ 
                    UserName:$scope.UserName,
                    Password:$scope.Password
                };
    var response=$http.post('http://localhost:8080/eHealthService/LoginAuthentication',formData);
    response.success(function(data, status,headers, config) {
        if(data.Status==10)
        {
           $localStorage["Admin"] = {"Status":"10","Description":"Admin is    logged"};
        }

    }); 
};
```

});

`$localStorage["Admin"] = {"Status":"10","Description":"Admin is    logged"};` this line is not working in service response. if i write this above $scope.submit function then its worked fine.

Comment: So is the request succeeding? Does the condition `if(data.Status==10)` return true? Some extra debugging details would be helpful

Comment: `if(data.Status==10` this condition return true. @charlietfl

Comment: issue is there that LocalStorage not working inside $scope.submit method.

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces issue